# Creating SQL commands to retrieve data from given tables

Tags: mysql, sql, tuples, row, having

Good day, I am a college student and lately we had an assignment where we were tasked to write SQL commands on various questions depending on the information that is needed to be displayed from 3 different tables. Here are the instructions and a sample question with a provided solution:

[Instructions + Sample Question & Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBFAO.png)

[Given Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkMkK.png)

And below are my answers:

[My Solved Questions Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5rDR.png)

[My Solved Questions Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmkHR.png)

What I would like to know is if there are any more ways to shorten each one of my answers for the 7 questions, preferably the shortest code possible. As a curious person, efficiency matters to me and it is ideal to use much shorter commands. For example, I am most definitely sure that this code from #7 could be shortened:

```
SELECT  pNo, MAX(qty), (SELECT MAX(qty) FROM sp WHERE pNo IN (SELECT pNo                 
FROM p WHERE pName = 'Nut' OR pName = 'Cam') ) AS MAXcamORnut
FROM            sp
GROUP BY        pno
HAVING      MAX(qty) > ALL (SELECT qty FROM sp WHERE pNo IN(SELECT pNo FROM 
p
WHERE pName = 'Nut' OR pName = 'Cam'));
```

Other than that, I also have two remaining unsolved questions here that I have no clue how to solve, any starting ideas would be appreciated. Thank you guys in advance :)

[Unsolved Questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEvr8.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), look around, and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Answer (score 0):

For reducing the clutter in SQL queries you could try CTEs (Common Table Expressions) instead of subqueries.

Example:

```
WITH cte_sel_max as (
  SELECT nestID, max(eggID) as last_own_egg from nests where own_egg = TRUE group by nestID
)
select eggs.nestID, 
       eggs.eggID as false_egg_ID
  from eggs join cte_sel_max cte 
  on (eggs.nestID=cte.nestID and eggID > last_own_egg)
```

Answering assignment questions directly are out of scope of this website ;)